# Intuitive way of thinking about function composition and partial application

Tags: javascript, closures, scheme, sicp, function-composition

This is a question I found in SICP, translated to JavaScript.

```
let double = function(f) {
  return function(x) {
    return(f(f(x)))
  }
}

let succ = x => x + 1
let ans = double(double)(double)(succ)(0)
console.log(ans) // What's the output?
```

This is my thought process:

Applying `double` to `double` results in a function that quadruples a given function.

Supplying `double` to this quadrupling function results in a function that applies a given function 8 times.

Therefore, the result should be 8. But the result is 16.

By substituting the double function and solving it by brute-force, I get 16 but am unable to intuitively grasp why. I understand function composition and partial applicatin in isolation, but not in this context.

What is happening here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*TL;DR:* functional composition is like multiplication. squaring something *4* times means raising it to the *16* th power. `double` should have been named *`squared`*.

---

This is *very* easy with  *equational* notation:

```hs
double(f)(x) = f(f(x)) = (f . f)(x)               -- (f^2)(x) ... why? see below:
```

where

```hs
(f . g)(x) = f(g(x))
```

by definition. Then, substituting the above equation's right-hand side for its left-hand side, and even left-hand side for its right-hand side, as it suits us, we have

```hs
double(double)(double)(succ)(0)                   -- double(double) = 
=
(double . double)(double)(succ)(0)                --           = double^2
=
double(double(double))(succ)(0)                   -- (double^2)(double) =
=                                   
double((double . double))(succ)(0)                --           = double(double^2)
=
((double . double) . (double . double))(succ)(0)       --      = double^4 !!
```

(no *`succ`* is involved, yet!). Deriving `f = g` from `f(x) = g(x)` is known as *eta-contraction*.

Function composition is associative,

```hs
((f . g) . h)(x) = (f . g)(h(x)) = f(g(h(x)))
                 = f( (g . h)(x) )
                 = (f . (g . h))(x)
```

so we continue

```hs
((double . double) . (double . double))(succ)(0)
=
(double . double . double . double)(succ)(0)   -- = f . f . f . f = f^4
=
double(double(double(double(succ))))(0)    -- = (double^4)(succ)
=
double(double(double(succ^2)))(0)     -- = (double^3)(succ^2) , succ^2 = succ . succ
=
double(double(succ^4))(0)       -- = (double^2)(succ^4)
=
double(succ^8)(0)         -- = (double^1)(succ^8)
=
(succ^16)(0)         -- = (double^0)(succ^16) = identity(succ^16) = succ^16
=
16
```

So this comes down to not mixing up  `(f . g)`  and `f(g)`.

Also, that *doubling* the multiplication chain means *squaring*.

Comment: I understand most of your explanation, but still find it hard to wrap my head around the transition from `(double . double)(double)` to `double(double(double))`. Can you please elaborate why double applied to double-squared becomes `double(double(double))`?

Comment: Never mind, I got it. If my understanding is not wrong, the transition is based on the earlier statement `(f . g)(x) = f(g(x))`. Thanks for the fantastic explanation! It would help if you could indicate this somewhere in your working.

Comment: yessa, exactamundo! :) (I'll try and see how.) Happy trails!

Comment: @MohideenImranKhan tweaked it. (found a pair of missing parens because of it!). see if it's better... :)

Comment: Yup, it's definitely better!

Comment: a fact often ignored, human cognition is very much visually-oriented. the more visual aids we can get, the easier it is to (some of) us to cognize!

Comment: Really nice working out. In lambda calculus it seems that "`double`" is the same as `power` with the two arguments being the same and thus `square` seems to be a simplification when it actually is `f↑↑2`

Comment: @Sylwester thanks. double(succ) = succ . succ = succ^2, isn't it? double(double)(double) = (double^2)(double) = double(double^2) = double^4 - again, "squared" fits the bill, no?

Comment: In lambda calculus power is defined as `λb.λe.e b`. In our case `b` and `e` is the same and thus `λf.f f` and it looks a lot like "`double`". I'm thinking perhaps `double` isn't such a bad name since it really doubly applies its arguments and that the magic here is that you pass it double which is more meta than `succ`. In your example you end with `(double . double . double . double)(inc)` which will "double" the previous action, thus inc becomes `(inc . inc)`, then `(inc . inc . inc . inc)`, ... and we end up with 16.. inc*2*2*2*2=inc*2^4

Comment: If `n^x` is notation for `(n0 . n1 ... nx)` then I understand the use of `square`.  Then it's more of a consequence of the naming convention rather than the operation.

Comment: @Sylwester `double` is `λf.B f f` though. `two n = B n n = mult n n`. hence *squared*. more scribblings [here](https://gist.github.com/WillNess/b3b7dea00f21960eb7b200d8ceee6bcb)

Answer (score 2):

This is really a question about associativity. In Racket (works the same in JS), compare these:

```
#lang racket

(define (double f) (λ (x) (f (f x))))

((double (double (double add1))) 0) ; => 8, as you hypothesized
((((double double) double) add1) 0) ; => 16, as you observed.
```

So the only difference is that function application is left-associative.

If you take your JS and add more parens to force right-associativity, you should see the "8" that you expect.

Answer (score 1):

This is not the easiest thing to explain but I'll try my best.
I will use Scheme since that's what I'm familiar with.

```
(define (double f)
  (lambda (x)
    (f (f x))))

(define (succ x)
  (+ x 1))

(double double)
; evaluates to
(lambda (x)
  (double (double x)))
; so
((double double) succ)
; is the same as
(double (double succ))
; which is the same as
(double (lambda (x)
          (succ (succ x))))
; lets call that last lambda inc2
; the last statement then equals
(inc2 (inc2 x))
; so when we call 
(((double double) succ) 0)
; we get 4 calls to succ, and the result is 4

; now let's add another double
((double double) double)
; this evaluates to
((lambda (x)
   (double (double x)))
 double)
; or
(double (double double))
; or
(double (lambda (x)
          (double (double x))))
; lets call that last lambda quadruple
(double quadruple)
; or
(lambda (x)
  (quadruple (quadruple x)))

; 4x4 is 16 and so when we call
((((double double) double) succ) 0)
; we call succ 16 times

; this in contrast to
((double (double (double succ))) 0)
; which will in fact return 8
```

It comes down to the way you call double.
Every time you call double with as argument double, the amount of calls increases to 2^(amount of calls to double).
When you call double on an already doubled function instead, you get the behaviour you would expect, and the amount of calls does indeed just double every time.

I'm sorry if this isn't very clear, I couldn't find an intuitive way to explain.